# How to get a compilation error when a permission is missing from the manifest

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse, Is there a way to get a compilation error when a required permission is missing in the manifest?

My app was not working as intended then I realized the only thing missing was a permission in the manifest. Getting an error could save me some time the next time this happens.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually missing permissions are easy to spot in your logcat output. So whenever your app crashes and logcat says something about permissions then take a look at your Manifest

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this feature is currently not available in ADT, which is where it would need to be implemented. It has however been requested. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60631